# Syntax error after adding WHERE. SQLite in R

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, having

I have a data of flights that includes Orgin, Dest and Month.
I'm trying to be able to get the freq of flights from Origin to Dest in a month across the year.

I've done:

```
dbGetQuery(conn,"
                 SELECT
                  Month AS Month,
                  COUNT(OriDes) AS Freq,
                  OriDes 
                 FROM(
                  SELECT Origin || '-' || Dest AS OriDes,
                  Month AS Month
                  FROM flights
                  )
                 GROUP BY OriDes, Month
                 ")
```

by first combining Origin and Dest from database then counting the frequency of it to get output of:

```
   Month Freq  OriDes
1      1  123 ABE-ATL
2      2  140 ABE-ATL
3      3  117 ABE-ATL
4      4  112 ABE-ATL
5      5  111 ABE-ATL
6      6  120 ABE-ATL
7      7  113 ABE-ATL
8      8  124 ABE-ATL
9      9   94 ABE-ATL
10    10  119 ABE-ATL
11    11  116 ABE-ATL
12    12  124 ABE-ATL
13     6    1 ABE-AVP
14     1   66 ABE-CLE
15     2   72 ABE-CLE
16     3   99 ABE-CLE
17     4   89 ABE-CLE
18     5   91 ABE-CLE
19     6   97 ABE-CLE
20     7   92 ABE-CLE
```

but because this is a large data I hope to filter and only deal with Freq > 500. So I tried:

```
dbGetQuery(conn,"
                 SELECT
                  Month AS Month,
                  COUNT(OriDes) AS Freq,
                  OriDes 
                 FROM(
                  SELECT Origin || '-' || Dest AS OriDes,
                  Month AS Month
                  FROM flights
                  )
                 GROUP BY OriDes, Month
                 WHERE Freq > 500
                 ")
```

but I'll get an error:

```
Error: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

Can someone explain to me what I've done wrong?

Comment: `WHERE` goes before `GROUP BY`, you want `HAVING`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate directly in the table without a subquery and all you need is a `HAVING` clause to filter the results of the aggregation and not a `WHERE` clause which filters the table before the aggregation:

```
SELECT Month,
       COUNT(*) AS Freq,
       Origin || '-' || Dest AS OriDes
FROM flights
GROUP BY Month, OriDes
HAVING Freq > 500;
```

Note that since you are using `OriDes` in the `GROUP BY` clause there is no point to use it inside `COUNT()`. You can count with `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

As it was suggested in the comments:

```sql
SELECT
Month AS Month,
COUNT(OriDes) AS Freq,
OriDes 
FROM(
     SELECT Origin || '-' || Dest AS OriDes,
     Month AS Month
     FROM flights
     )
GROUP BY OriDes, Month
HAVING COUNT(OriDes) > 500
```